# Big-O & Runing Time of this algorthm , how can convert this to an iterative algorthm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, iteration, big-o

What is the runing time of this algorthm in Big-O and how i convert this to iterative algorthm?

```
 public static int RecursiveMaxOfArray(int[] array) {
    int array1[] = new int[array.length/2];
    int array2[] = new int[array.length - (array.length/2)];

    for (int index = 0; index < array.length/2 ; index++) {
        array1[index] = array[index];
    }
    for (int index = array.length/2; index < array.length; index++) {
        array2[index - array.length/2] = array[index] ;
    }

    if (array.length > 1) {
        if(RecursiveMaxOfArray(array1) > RecursiveMaxOfArray(array2)) {
            return RecursiveMaxOfArray(array1) ;
        }
        else {
            return RecursiveMaxOfArray(array2) ;
        }
    }
    return array[0] ;

}
```

Comment: What analysis have you done?

Comment: i wrote divide&conquer algorithm but I dont know runing time in Big-O , and how can I convert to an iterative algorithm

Comment: Why do you call `RecursiveMaxOfArray` a second time when returning? Just cache the return result and return *that*.

Comment: Is the array sorted?

Answer (score 1):

At each stage, an array of size N is divided into equal halves. The function is then recursively called **three** times on an array of size N/2. Why three instead of the four which are written? Because the if statement only enters one of its clauses. Therefore the recurrence relation is `T(N) = 3T(N/2) + O(N)`, which (using the [*Master theorem*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))) gives `O(N^[log2(3)]) = O(n^1.58)`.

However, you don't need to call it for the third time; just cache the return result of each recursive call in a local variable. The coefficient 3 in the recurrence relation becomes 2; I'll leave it to you to apply the Master theorem on the new recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

There's another answer that accurately describes your algorithm's runtime complexity, how to determine it, and how to improve it, so I won't focus on that. Instead, let's look at the other part of your question:

> how [do] i convert this to [an] iterative algorithm?

Well, there's a straightforward solution to that which you hopefully could have gotten yourself - loop over the list and track the smallest value you've seen so far.

However, I'm guessing your question is better phrased as this:

> How do I convert a recursive algorithm into an iterative algorithm?

There are plenty of questions and answers on this, not just here on StackOverflow, so I suggest you do some more research on this subject. [These blog posts on converting recursion to iteration](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html) may be an excellent place to start if this is your approach to take, though I can't vouch for them because I haven't read them. I just googled "convert recursion to iteration," picked the first result, then found this page which links to all four of the blog post.